# umbraco forms posting from protected page gives ysod

Tags: asp.net, forms, umbraco

Using Umbraco version 7.4.3 assembly: 1.0.5948.18141
After creating a form using umbraco 7.4.3 the form works as expected, except when we access the form via a protected page. The form displays, and allows user interaction, however we are unable to submit form from protected page.

There was a question posed on the umbraco forum that suggested a fix was found, but no information for that fix was posted here -> https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-forms/78933-umbraco-forms-and-protected-pages, 
I have also posted a question regarding this issue in the umbraco forums - no answer todate.

YSOD when submitting form from a protected page. Stack trace below:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Umbraco.Core.Cache.HttpRuntimeCacheProvider.GetCacheItem(String
>   cacheKey, Func1 getCacheItem, Nullable1 timeout, Boolean isSliding,
>   CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback,
>   CacheDependency dependency) +825
>   Umbraco.Core.Cache.HttpRuntimeCacheProvider.GetCacheItem(String
>   cacheKey, Func1 getCacheItem, Nullable1 timeout, Boolean isSliding,
>   CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback,
>   String[] dependentFiles) +200
>   Umbraco.Core.Cache.DeepCloneRuntimeCacheProvider.GetCacheItem(String
>   cacheKey, Func1 getCacheItem, Nullable1 timeout, Boolean isSliding,
>   CacheItemPriority priority, CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback,
>   String[] dependentFiles) +183
>   Umbraco.Forms.Core.Cache.CacheProviderExtensions.GetCacheItem(IRuntimeCacheProvider
>   provider, String cacheKey, Func1 getCacheItem, Nullable1 timeout,
>   Boolean isSliding, CacheItemPriority priority,
>   CacheItemRemovedCallback removedCallback, String[] dependentFiles)
>   +541 Umbraco.Forms.Data.StringHelper.ParseMemberPlaceholders(String value, Object memberKey) +1990
>   Umbraco.Forms.Data.StringHelper.ParsePlaceHolders(HttpContext context,
>   Record record, String value) +584
>   Umbraco.Forms.Data.StringHelper.ParsePlaceHolders(Record record,
>   String value) +75
>   Umbraco.Forms.Core.Services.WorkflowService.ExecuteWorkflows(List1
>   workflows, RecordEventArgs e) +1158
>   Umbraco.Forms.Core.Services.WorkflowService.ExecuteWorkflows(Record
>   record, Form form, FormState state, Boolean editMode) +468
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Services.RecordService.Submit(Record record, Form
>   form) +704
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Controllers.UmbracoFormsController.SubmitForm(Form
>   form, FormViewModel model, Dictionary2 state, ControllerContext
>   context) +3103
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Controllers.UmbracoFormsController.GoForward(Form
>   form, FormViewModel model, Dictionary2 state) +339
>   Umbraco.Forms.Web.Controllers.UmbracoFormsController.HandleForm(FormViewModel
>   model, Boolean captchaIsValid) +1283    lambda_method(Closure ,
>   ControllerBase , Object[] ) +167
>   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IDictionary2 parameters) +217
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary2
>   parameters) +39
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.b__39(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +139
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b3d() +112
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass46.b3f() +452
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass46.b3f() +452
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass46.b3f() +452
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass46.b3f() +452
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass46.b3f() +452
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass33.b32(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +15 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass2b.b1c() +37 System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>cDisplayClass21.b1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +241 System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +19 System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +51
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +111
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +606 System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +288

Answer (score 0):

There is a reply in the thread you've mentioned: https://our.umbraco.org/forum/umbraco-forms/78933-umbraco-forms-and-protected-pages#comment-256103. Hope it'll help you :)